# jQuery Validate UK Postcode

Tags: jquery, regex, jquery-validate

I have built a script to lookup flood areas via postcode and I'm looking to validate the field, I currently have a custom jQuery Validate method as the following.

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("postcodeUK", function (value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /[A-z]{1,2}[0-9]{1,2} ?[0-9][A-Z]{2}/i.test(value);
}, "Please specify a valid Postcode");
```

The only issue is I require the space in-between for example AB12 3CD or BC1 9GH. It current allows AB123CD or BC19GH.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've made the space optional by following it with `?`. If you want to require it, remove that `?`.

A couple of other notes:

- `[A-z]` is not just A-Z and a-z but also `[`, `\`, `]`, `_`, and backtick (the characters between `Z` and `a`). Since you're using the `i` flag, you want `[A-Z]` or `[a-z]` there.
- You probably want `^` at the beginnning and `$` at the end to match against the whole input, not just a subset.

[Example on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/oW4kO8/2) *(you don't need the `g` or `m` flags I used there, that was just so I could show multiple examples in the testing area)*

Comment: Thank you, that's perfect! :)

Answer (score 4):

There is already a *proven* method for validating UK Postcodes contained within [the `additional-methods.js` file](http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.15.0/additional-methods.js) of the jQuery Validate plugin.  Include [this file](http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.15.0/additional-methods.js) or simply copy the method into your code, and then use the `postcodeUK` rule.

```
// Matches UK postcode. Does not match to UK Channel Islands that have their own postcodes (non standard UK)
$.validator.addMethod( "postcodeUK", function( value, element ) {
    return this.optional( element ) || /^((([A-PR-UWYZ][0-9])|([A-PR-UWYZ][0-9][0-9])|([A-PR-UWYZ][A-HK-Y][0-9])|([A-PR-UWYZ][A-HK-Y][0-9][0-9])|([A-PR-UWYZ][0-9][A-HJKSTUW])|([A-PR-UWYZ][A-HK-Y][0-9][ABEHMNPRVWXY]))\s?([0-9][ABD-HJLNP-UW-Z]{2})|(GIR)\s?(0AA))$/i.test( value );
}, "Please specify a valid UK postcode" );
```

Comment: @sanjeetbisht - if it's not working properly, file a bug report with the developer.